# where are the second stage bootloader and partition table is stored in the case of multiple bootable hard drives

Tags: partitioning, multi-boot, bootloader

I have some doubt on the booting process. Lets suppose I have two bootable hard drives and each hard drive has 3 partition, having 3 different operating system installed. Now my questions are:

1. How the booting process will get know from which hard disk to boot?
2. Where is Second stage boot loader stored?
3. What is there in the active partition? (I know that active partition is one of the primary partition but then why we are giving special reference to one primary partition )
4. Can anyone give me a link for how POST (power on self test) process is done?

Comment: I suggest you limit yourself to one question per question. ;) While the first three are roughly related, the fourth is totally off-topic.

Comment: @DanielB ok i will keep it in mind in future